# In Wagtail, how to list Pages which are Live and have no privacy setting?

Tags: wagtail

On a [Wagtail](https://wagtail.io) site, the standard way to get a list of live Pages is something like:

```
MyPage.objects.live()
```

However, I want to ensure that I only display pages that are live *and* have no privacy/visibility setting other than 'Public'. So, to only list pages that *every* user to the site can see.

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with

```
MyPage.objects.live().public()
```

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/queryset_reference.html#wagtail.core.query.PageQuerySet.public

Comment: Oh, that was easy :) Thank you @gasman. I should have noticed this ages ago and used that everywhere from the start!